# "You have reached your question limit" - What can I do?

Tags: support, questions, asking

Can someone explain why my account is blocked when I asked for the logic of legend experience in Dying Light?

What can I do to get back my account to healthy condition?

Answer (score 5):

When you are unable to ask questions, the notification has a [link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) for you to follow, to understand what is happening.  The basic answer is that you have a history of low quality questions, and the system doesn't think your next one will be much better.  One important point is that it's not a single question that does it, but a history of low quality questions.

To remove the question ban, the idea is that you're supposed to go through your low quality content and improve them; it's meant to be a general incentive to improve, not pinpoint a single question as the problem, and improving that one solves it.

---

Now, the more in-depth answer:

You have a total of twelve questions; five of them are deleted, and at least three of those are at least at -4 or lower.  That's bad.  Of your remaining questions, you have a total of two upvotes across all of them.  That's not a good track record in any sense.  There's usually a way to see recently deleted questions, which, for you, you could find [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/57979).  Problem is, none of your deleted questions are recent enough to show up in that list; the earliest is in February.  Best I can do is point you at them, but it doesn't look like they could be edited into something we'd accept.  You've probably been in the question ban for a while, but you get another chance every six months, so since you ask questions so rarely, you might not have been blocked before.

Now, what can you do?  Reading the first link is a good start; it gives some good pointers, and I'd like to highlight a couple key areas:

- Deleted questions still count.  If they didn't, it would be trivially easy to bypass the ban.
- We moderators, nor even Stack Exchange employees, can't lift the ban.  It's system imposed, and can only be removed by the system itself.

A couple points that are not in the above information:

- Do not try to bypass the ban with another account; the question ban is user targeted, and you need to follow the process, not work around it.
- You can ask Stack Exchange to disassociate some poorly received questions from your account.  You can do so by using the contact link at the bottom of each page, and an employee can review and help you out.  Note that this isn't a common process; there's no guarantee that posts will be disassociated, and you may have to live with it.

Other than that, the best advice we can give is to improve your questions, and after six months, asking another one that's the best it can be.  Make it count.  Good luck!